# Is there a way to model a mongo database?

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql

I'm looking for a way to model a mongo database for my graduation project.

Is it correct if I use a schema as below:

```
{

    "bsonType":"object",
    
    "required":["question_text","question_date"],
    
    "properties:{
    
        "question_text":{"bsonType":"string"},
    
        "question_date":{"bsonType":"date"},
    
            }
}
```